# Derivative of power sum?

Tags: derivatives, summation

In one part of a proof I'm reading I see the following:

$$ p\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k = p\frac{1}{1-p} $$

However, I'm confused how the derivative of $\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k = \frac{1}{1-p}$, wouldn't it equal $\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}$?

Here's a picture of the actual two lines as I've stripped them to the part I'm confused about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkqSQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The calculation stated in *https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiQYt.jpg* is not correct.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{E[N^2]}&=\ldots=(1-\rho)\rho\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\rho\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \rho^i\right)\right)\\
> &=(1-\rho)\rho\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\rho\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\frac{1}{1-\rho}\right)\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=(1-\rho)\rho\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\rho\frac{(1-\rho)(0)-(1)(-1)}{(1-\rho)^2}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=(1-\rho)\rho\frac{d}{d\rho}\left(\frac{\rho}{(1-\rho)^2}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=(1-\rho)\rho\cdot\frac{(1-\rho)^2(1)-(\rho)2(1-\rho)(-1)}{(1-\rho)^4}\tag{4}\\
> &=(1-\rho)\rho\cdot\frac{1+\rho}{(1-\rho)^3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{\rho(1+\rho)}{(1-\rho)^2}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use   the *[geometric  series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (2) we apply  the *[quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule)* in the same manner as it is presented in the referred image.
- In (3) we do some simplifications and continue in (4) as we did in (2).

> With $E[N]=\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}$ we finally conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{Var(N)}&=E[N^2]-E^2[N]\\
> &=\frac{\rho(1+\rho)}{(1-\rho)^2}-\frac{\rho^2}{(1-\rho)^2}\\
> &=\frac{\rho+\rho^2-\rho^2}{(1-\rho)^2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{\rho}{(1-\rho)^2}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You are right, I think, because

$$\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k = (\frac{1}{1-p})'=\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}$$

Comment: Im so confused :(

Comment: In fact this shows that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp^{k-1}=\frac 1{(1-p)^2}$